# handling refrence to pointers/double pointers using SWIG [C++ to Java]

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, swig

My code has an interface like

`class IExample { ~IExample(); //pure virtual methods ...};`

a class inheriting the interface like

`class CExample : public IExample { protected: CExample(); //implementation of pure virtual methods ... };`

and a global function to create object of this class -

`createExample( IExample *& obj ) { obj = new CExample(); } ;`

Now, I am trying to get Java API wrapper using SWIG, the SWIG generated interface has a construcotr like - `IExample(long cPtr, boolean cMemoryOwn)` and global function becomes `createExample(IExample obj )`

The problem is when i do,

`IExample exObject = new IExample(ExampleLibraryJNI.new_plong(), true /*or false*/ );
ExampleLibrary.createExample( exObject );`

The `createExample(...)` API at C++ layer succesfully gets called, however, when call returns to Java layer, the `cPtr (long)` variable does not get updated. Ideally, this variable should contain address of `CExample` object.

I read in documentation that typemaps can be used to handle output parameters and pointer references as well; however, I am not able to figure out the suitable way to use typemaps to resolve this problem, or any other workaround.

Please suggest if i am doing something wrong, or how to use typemap in such situation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you'd solve this problem with typemaps; Java doesn't support reference parameters so the conversion would be very complicated.

Why not just have `createExample()` return an `IExample*`? If you need the return value for something else, I recommend returning `std::pair<IExample*,OtherThing>`, or some similar structured type.